# How to load a data warehouse dimension from a slowly changing entity?

Tags: database, etl, scd, warehouse

I'm creating some dimensions from a source system (OLTP) which already tracks changes to rows using the Kimball type 2 method. I read in his latest book he calls these "Slowly Changing Entities" but he doesn't explain how to load them into a data warehouse.

Currently my idea is to just copy the "Valid From" and "Valid To" fields from the live database and use those in my type 2 dimensions instead of the usual method of using the current day - 1 to expire the rows. This way the dimensions will be the same as the live tables.

When loading data I will then have to join on the natural key AND the "Valid From" date to match up the rows (since the source table will repeat the natural key due to being type 2).

Does anyone see any problem with my approach in basically using the source system to track changes?

Comment: There does not seem to be enough context information in your question to get a decent answer (although, in fairness, I'm not an expert in this domain): Dimensions in what sense? "Already tracks changes to rows" - why "already"? Are you "tracking changes to rows"? In what sense? What exactly is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: In a data warehouse you often have type 2 slowly changing dimensions which you use to track changes in the source system by "expiring" a row by adding a "Valid To" date to it whenever you detect a change to the source data. This is so reports show the entities as they were when each fact was loaded.

Comment: For example, if a salesperson changes teams, you don't want to show past sales as belonging to their current team. My question is whether it's recommended to use the source "Valid To" to expire my rows(the source system already tracks changes by using "Valid From" and "Valid To" fields). So I'm effectively loading from a type 2 slowly changing table into a Type 2 SCD in my data warehouse.